# Calculating log and trigonometric functions using only +,-,/,*

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms

How to calculate logarithm and trigonometric functions (sin, cos etc.) on base n with using +,-,/,* ?

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: $ \sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} \cdots $ where $x$ is in radians. Similar expansions exist for $\cos \text{ and } \log $.

Comment: [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) and [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) are the usual first approaches.

Comment: there's a good list of them here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html

Comment: Wow, that's more than enough for me. Thank you community! `:)`

Comment: An **important** hint for actual computations: The first step should be a range reduction to the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ or better $[-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$. Otherwise you may get problems with convergence or rounding errors.